# SpringBoot SecurityConfig ignore onAuthenticationSuccess

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I need to do custom action after login success or fail, So i implemented a class that extend the SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler

```
public class CustomSimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {


@Override
public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
    System.out.println("On authentication failure");
    super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);
}
```

}

and also a class thta extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler

```
public class CustomSimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {


@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
    System.out.println("On authentication success");
    super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
}
```

}

then i put it into the securityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true
)
@Order(SecurityProperties.IGNORED_ORDER)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler(){
        return new CustomSimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler();
    };

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler(){
        return new CustomSimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    };


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .httpBasic().and()
            .authorizeRequests()

            .antMatchers("/api/open/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                .ignoringAntMatchers("/api/open/**")
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl(UrlConfigurator.API_LOGIN) //   /api/login
                .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler())
                .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler())
            .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/api/logout")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
//          .and().antMatcher("/api/service/**").csrf().disable().httpBasic()
        // @formatter:on
        ;
    }
    
}
```

but the print commands are not executed in any way... wats's wrong?

Thanks for your attention

Comment: Looks like you have both HTTP basic and form authentication enabled. Can you elaborate on the steps you're taking once you run the application, what API(s) you're hitting and how you authenticate. Can you provide your CustomUserDetailsService and any relevant logs?

Comment: You need authentication filter and adding the login api to it more over you need to over ride attempt authentication too .

Answer (score -1):

The definition of the success handler looks good to me.

## Bean Definition

However, you need to define the Bean outside the Bean consumer.

```java
@Component
public class CustomSimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {
```

## Consume the Bean

```java
// delete this
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler(){
        return new CustomSimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    };

// autowire the bean instead.
@Autowired
private AuthenticationSuccessHandler customSimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
```

```java
// This is wrong.
.successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler())

// This is right because you are using the bean here.
.successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
```

## Problem

The problem in your code is that, you instantiate `CustomSimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler` with `return new CustomSimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler();`. In this way, you are not using the bean.

You only want to pass a singleton bean into `.successHandler()`.